# DatetimePicker automatic conversion C#

Tags: c#

I am using C# and I am setting the value of the date time picker to my date from my database. But the format I have in database is different from the format of the Date Time Picker. Is there a way to automatically change the format of my database date to that of the date time picker. I have searched for it but I haven't found it.

I will appreciate your help.

Comment: It would help if you would show what format the Date in your database looks like.. also what is the datatype if you were to look at the SQL Schema for that date field..?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But the format I have in database is different from the format of the Date Time Picke

You are making the mistake of thinking the database has any associated display format when storing a `DATETIME` - it doesn't - there is an internal representation. All you see is how the date is represented when you view it in some tool.

If your database uses a `DATETIME` column, as it should, then there is not issue.

Comment: @Stranger - No. There is no format. That's just what you see in whatever tool you are using to view the data.

Comment: So if I take my date from the database and set my datetime picker's value to the database date, will it work?

Comment: @Stranger - yes. That's how it works. You only format when you _display_.